# Jquery, load multi dimensional array from PHP and access their elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a two dimensional array from PHP, now I want to access each position of the array, to add it to an  HTML element.

My actual code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var stores = <?php echo json_encode($stores); ?>;
        console.log(stores[2][0])
    });
</script>
```

Sadly the console returns "undefined".

How could I access for example only the id of the second store?

Comment: What about `console.log( stores[2]['id'] );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `id` property of the second array element that way:

```
console.log( stores[2].id );
```

or

```
console.log( stores[2]['id'] );
```